# Error trying to assign multiple ID's from an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Here I have an association between an User and a Subreddit. Where a User can subscribe to multiple Subreddits and a Subreddit can have multiple users subscribed to it.

I am trying to pull the feed (posts) from those Subreddits into my view page like so:

```
def home
  @subscriptions = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user)
  @posts = Post.where(:subreddit_id => @subscriptions.subreddit_id)
end
```

Obviously this is not going to work since @subscriptions is an Array of Subscriptions.

I have tried doing a loop like so:

```
@subscriptions.each do |s|
  @posts = Post.where(:subreddit_id => s.subreddit_id)
end
```

That doesn't work and @posts ends up being nil.
My question is:
How can I pull out the subreddit_id from Subscriptions and transfer it into my @posts variable?

edit:

Tables- (subscription is a bridge table between users and a subreddit)

```
Subscription  
------------
id
user_id
subreddit_id

User
------------
id
username
email

Subreddit
------------
id
subname

Post
-----------
id
subreddit_id
title
url
content
```

Comment: Which are your models? User and Subscription? What is a subreddit? Another model? Answer and I will give your solution.

Comment: All three of them are models

Comment: Please edit your content and try to explain your columns or try to draw a table, sometimes we read minds but please try to explain clear

Comment: Stavros Souvatzis got the answer go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your home definition, check first your user.rb (model) class. You should have:

```
has_many :subscriptions
```

If you have those, then your  `def home` would become:

```
def home
    @subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions # active record is magical
    subscriptions = @subscriptions.map(&:subreddit_id)
    @posts = Post.where('subreddit_id in (?)', subscriptions)
end
```

If you don't

```
def home
    @subscriptions = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id) # YOU NEED THE ID!
    subscriptions = @subscriptions.map(&:subreddit_id)
    @posts = Post.where('subreddit_id in (?)', subscriptions)
end
```

If you don't need @subscriptions for your view, you can just combine the first two lines into one:

```
def home
    subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions.map(&:subreddit_id)
    @posts = Post.where('subreddit_id in (?)', subscriptions)
end
```

Comment: I'm agree you got it but the person who asked didn't know what question did =)